# Is there a routine like FETCH, STASH and SWAP for transfering data between memory bank 0 and 1 on the C128?

Tags: commodore-128

The BASIC 7.0 of the C128 provides commands for copying a block of bytes between an REU (RAM expansion unit) and memory in Bank 0 or 1. For those who do not own an REU, is there a function for copying a block of data between two memory areas across banks 0 and 1? From reading the BASIC 7.0 documentation I did not find an appropriate BASIC command for this, but is there a machine language routine in the ROM that can be called from BASIC and does the job?

The alternative of using a FOR-loop in BASIC 7.0: `FOR I=source TO I+length-1:BANK 0:A=PEEK(I):BANK 1:POKE target-source+I,A:NEXT` is really slow.

Answer (score 5):

No there is no equivalent BASIC command. In fact, even REU commands (FETCH/STASH/SWAP) can not copy between the C128's two banks, but only between whatever bank has been selected (*1) ant the REU.

As a result copying a block from one bank into the other needs to go thru the REU. First transferred to the REU and then to the other Bank. For example to move 256 bytes fron $1000 in Bank 1 to $2000 in Bank 0 one needs to:

```
10 BANK 1 : SWAP 256, 1024, 0, 0  : REM Move from bank 1 to REU and save REU content
20 BANK 0 : FETCH 256, 2048, 0, 0 : REM Move from REU to Bank 0
30 BANK 1 : SWAP 256, 1024, 0, 0  : REM Restore REU content
```

Given, it will be comparably fast, still not really elegant.

The same process can of course be done using an external drive, like a floppy.

```
10 BSAVE "MOVEFILE", B1, P (1024) TO P (1024+256)
20 BLOAD "MOVEFILE", B0, P (2048)
30 SCRATCH "MOVEFILE"
```

Works, but might not be the fastest way. For short amounts the mentioned BASIC loop might be faster (*2,3).

Of course if a machine language routine is fine, that would speed it up a lot. The C128 Kernal offers a set of new calls to access a byte in any bank as described on p.405 of the *C128 Programmer's Reference Guide*:

```
16. $FF74 JMP INDFET ;LDA (fetvec),Y from any bank
17. $FF77 JMP INDSTA ;STA (stavec),Y to any bank
18. $FF7A JMP INDCMP ;CMP (cmpvec),Y to any bank
```

Using these a copy routine can be set up that should work acceptable fast while still being fairly hardware independent (*3,4).

---

*1 - By setting via `BANK n` or `POKE 981,n`

*2 - Maybe without that potential error and a tiny bit optimized:

```
last=length-1
FOR I=0 TO last:BANK 0:A=PEEK(start+I):BANK 1:POKE target+I,A:NEXT
```

*3 - Another idea could be using the common RAM area as intermediate buffer - not sure how well that might work from BASIC

*4 - I'm not sure, but it might be worth to take a look at using the 8563 RAM as buffer intermediate buffer.

Comment: "Maybe without that error" - which error?

Comment: @PeterB. `FOR I=source TO I+length-1` is a rather dubios construct, isn't it?

Comment: The end address of the for loop is calculated once and put onto the stack, Thus, the first value of I counts for the calculation and the expression is only evaluated once. Would not count that as error.

Comment: @PeterB. You're right, it works with Commodore BASIC, that's why it's a footnote, which usually contain my opinion on various topic. I would think of it as hard to read and not really BASIC, but using of side effects. Kind of a premature optimization. Same as the `target-source+I` expression which may yield a negative number as address, which again is not a universal feature.

Comment: The result of ``target-source+I`` never is negative because ``I`` is always at least as large as ``source``. But yes, the intermediate result after the first subtraction might be negative. 
BTW, thank you for your great idea about using the disk as a buffer. In a test with the 1571 floppy, this was four times faster than the optimized BASIC loop (1MHz mode).  In your answer about the disk example, the comma is missing in line 10 and 20 after the B-parameter in BSAVE/BLOAD. Also, I think the FOR loop was meant to use "last" instead of "length".

Comment: Oops, I'll correct that. I'm surprised that the Floppy is already faster with just 256 bytes.

Comment: I tested with a 4K area and got 16 seconds vs 65 seconds. For 256 bytes it is around 5 seconds for both, so not worth bothering the disk. 256 bytes means writing and reading 2 blocks, which is a bit unfortunate for the floppy team. With 506 bytes it is still 2 blocks on disk and the floppy solution wins with 6 vs 9 seconds.

Comment: @PeterB. Would you want to try that with STEP 2? (`FOR I=0 TO last STEP 2 :BANK 0:A=PEEK(start+I):B=PEEK(start+I+1):BANK 1:POKE target+I,A:POKE target+I+1,A:NEXT`) Just out of curiosity :))

Comment: The STEP 2 approach is 11% faster measured over 4K. Interestingly, a copy routine without the BANK commands would be slightly slower with STEP2 - what is saved on loop overhead is lost in the arithmetic for +1. But the reduced number of BANK commands contributes more. Nice intuition!

Comment: @PeterB. Thanks for trying. Was really just stabbing in the dark. From here on the usual BASIC fiddling (using vars etc.) may come. The whole memory management in BASIC 7 is not exactly great.